# Is there any other easy way to get the height and width of a container using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks `useEffect` to get the width and height of the `container`.
The problems I want to solve are:

1. I want to get the responsive container height/width and not the window height/width.
2. My Initial state is set to `window.innerHeight` and this itself crashes my output on the Initial render as I'm using the `dimension` state to get something done in the first place.
3. I want to use the latest methods which are much simpler.. may be useRef() or anything..

I'm new to this React Hooks and unaware of many things.. I want simple code which perfectly does the work.

My code is as below:

```
function debounce(fn, ms) {
    let timer;
    return (_) => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout((_) => {
            timer = null;
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }, ms);
    };
}

export default function App() {
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
            setDimensions({
                height: window.innerHeight,
                width: window.innerWidth,
            });
        }, 1000);

        document
            .getElementById('SldBox')
            .addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);

        return (_) => {
            document
                .getElementById('SldBox')
                .removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
        };
    });

    return (
        <div className='container' id='SldBox'>
            My Container
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cool problem, lots of hooks to be learned here.

Here is a sample of how we can use:

- useState
- useEffect
- useMemo
- useRef

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-poincare-c8mcz?file=/src/App.js

**useState**: You've made good use of this one. No need to explain it more.

**useRef**: Create a ref then pass it to your element.

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>stuff</div>
  );
}
```

Now after the first render, we can reference the element easily enough.

**useMemo**:  To set up an observer for an element we can use `ResizeObserver`. If we didn't wrap this in `useMemo`, we would be recreating this function on every render which is wasteful. `useMemo` remedies this. We also add a dependency array for `useMemo` as the second argument that includes `ref.current`. This way, anytime ref changes (like on the first render), the `elementObserver` function will be recalculated.

```
  const elementObserver = useMemo(() => {
    return new ResizeObserver(() => {
      debounce(() => {
        if (!ref.current) return;
        setDimensions({
          height: ref.current.clientHeight,
          width: ref.current.clientWidth
        });
      }, 1000)();
    });
  }, [ref.current]);
```

**useEffect**: Now we can just use `useEffect` to set the observer when the component mounts. Again we include a dependency array that tells the effect to trigger the callback function provided if any of these values are changed. It will also always run when the component mounts, so we need to check ref exists for this one. Also, assign the element to a variable in the effect for the "cleanup" function.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref) return;
    const element = ref.current;

    elementObserver.observe(element);
    return () => {
      elementObserver.unobserve(element);
    };
  }, [ref.current, elementObserver]);
```

Comment: I'm wondering about this question for a while: if you use React, is `ResizeObserver` really necessary? Could be a nice new API, but isn't `useEffect(..., [ref.current?.clientHeight])` sufficient for getting & updating the dynamic height.